# Apply function on rows across a column in a list

Tags: r, apply

I need to select a column from a list, `cbind` the columns, and perform a function on rows of such a combined dataset. I need to do this consequently for all columns. Inspired by the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13016620/5967807), I came up with a possible solution for one column:

```
x <- apply(Reduce("cbind", lapply(L, FUN = function(x) x[, 1])), 1, FUN = sd)
```

It is clunky and gets worse when expanded to include all columns. Let's have a list of matrices:

```
set.seed(2385737)
L = list(matrix(rnorm(30), ncol = 3), matrix(rnorm(30), ncol = 3), matrix(rnorm(30), ncol = 3))

X <- matrix(c(apply(Reduce("cbind", lapply(L, FUN = function(x) x[, 1])), 1, FUN = sd),
    apply(Reduce("cbind", lapply(L, FUN = function(x) x[, 2])), 1, FUN = sd),
    apply(Reduce("cbind", lapply(L, FUN = function(x) x[, 3])), 1, FUN = sd)),
    ncol = 3
)
```

I can generalise the code above into:

```
X <- sapply(1:ncol(L[[1]]), 
    FUN = function(i) apply(Reduce("cbind", 
        lapply(L, FUN = function(x) x[, i])), 1, FUN = sd))
```

Is there a clean way how to approach the calculation consequently for all columns across a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to stack the list of matrices into a single 3D array and perform the calculations directly on this array using `apply`. Although rarely used, the `MARGIN` argument in `apply` can be fed a vector of margin indices that allows calculations to be done on any dimension of the array, so using `MARGIN = c(1, 2)` will perform the `FUN` on the vectors along the third dimension.

This allows the whole thing to be done as a one-liner if you use the function `abind` from the `abind` package to create the array from your list.

```r
apply(do.call(abind::abind, c(L, along = 3)), c(1, 2), FUN = sd)
#>            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#>  [1,] 0.5040136 0.1593154 0.9371359
#>  [2,] 1.2781308 0.5380104 1.1967232
#>  [3,] 1.3355753 0.5445188 0.8851976
#>  [4,] 1.5333570 0.9800276 0.5928828
#>  [5,] 1.4844418 2.1511425 1.6904784
#>  [6,] 1.5158726 2.0156800 1.3566559
#>  [7,] 0.8452233 0.3058013 1.0896865
#>  [8,] 0.5742021 0.8816770 1.4622064
#>  [9,] 1.7673249 0.9863849 1.1386831
#> [10,] 0.9001773 1.0793596 0.5754467
```

This is the same result as `X` in your example above.

If you prefer to use base R without extra packages, you can create your array directly:

```r
apply(array(unlist(L), c(nrow(L[[1]]), ncol(L[[1]]), length(L))), c(1, 2), sd)
```

This gives the same result.

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit more please? Why is the margin argument in `apply` equal to `c(1, 2)`?

Comment: Sure, I've updated @nya. If you have a standard 2d matrix, passing `MARGIN = c(1, 2)` will perform the function at each unique row/column index of the matrix, so `FUN` will only have a single value passed to it. However, in a 3D array there are multiple values at each row/column index (one for each matrix 'slice'), and they all get passed as a vector. Since you have stacked your matrix slices together, this is equivalent to operating on the rows of cbinded columns.

Answer (score 3):

Benchmarking:

```
set.seed(1); L = lapply(1:100, function(i) matrix(rnorm(1000000), ncol = 1000))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  zx = {
    sapply(
      #transpose
      lapply(seq(ncol(L[[1]])), function(i)
        sapply(seq_along(L), function(j)
          L[[ j ]][, i ]
        )),
      #apply function
      function(i) apply(i, 1, sd))
  },
  sotos = {
    i1 <- seq(1, ncol(L[[1]]) * length(L), (ncol(L[[1]]) * length(L))/length(L))
    sapply(seq(0, (length(L)-1)), \(i)apply(do.call(cbind, L)[,i1+i], 1, sd))
    
  },
  allanAbind = {
    apply(do.call(abind::abind, c(L, along = 3)), c(1, 2), FUN = sd)
  },
  allanBase = {
    apply(array(unlist(L), c(nrow(L[[1]]), ncol(L[[1]]), length(L))), c(1, 2), sd)
  },
  times = 10
)
#Unit: seconds
#       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#         zx 19.66990 21.16743 24.33954 23.99107 27.29293 30.42287    10
#      sotos 43.45282 45.93170 48.76219 48.05993 51.02062 55.16740    10
# allanAbind 19.81033 21.69177 25.47289 23.96392 29.19223 35.03646    10
#  allanBase 21.69405 22.26512 26.29049 23.90017 28.06595 39.60385    10
```

Answer (score 2):

"Transpose" the list so that we have 3 (number of columns in a matrix) lists where each list contains nth column from original list **L**, i.e.: first one will have all first columns from all matrices.

Then loop through that list, and *apply* function per row:

```
sapply(
  #transpose
  lapply(seq(ncol(L[[1]])), function(i)
    sapply(seq_along(L), function(j)
      L[[ j ]][, i ]
    )),
  #apply function
  function(i) apply(i, 1, sd))

#            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#  [1,] 0.5040136 0.1593154 0.9371359
#  [2,] 1.2781308 0.5380104 1.1967232
#  [3,] 1.3355753 0.5445188 0.8851976
#  [4,] 1.5333570 0.9800276 0.5928828
#  [5,] 1.4844418 2.1511425 1.6904784
#  [6,] 1.5158726 2.0156800 1.3566559
#  [7,] 0.8452233 0.3058013 1.0896865
#  [8,] 0.5742021 0.8816770 1.4622064
#  [9,] 1.7673249 0.9863849 1.1386831
# [10,] 0.9001773 1.0793596 0.5754467
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go at it would be to create a sequence with the columns to be binded (i.e. in your case 1, 4, 7 - 2, 5, 8 - 3, 6, 9) and apply the `sd` function rowwise to each of the combinations, i.e.

```
i1 <- seq(1, ncol(L[[1]])* length(L), (ncol(L[[1]])*length(L))/length(L))
sapply(seq(0, (length(L)-1)), \(i)apply(do.call(cbind, L)[,i1+i], 1, sd))

           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
 [1,] 0.5040136 0.1593154 0.9371359
 [2,] 1.2781308 0.5380104 1.1967232
 [3,] 1.3355753 0.5445188 0.8851976
 [4,] 1.5333570 0.9800276 0.5928828
 [5,] 1.4844418 2.1511425 1.6904784
 [6,] 1.5158726 2.0156800 1.3566559
 [7,] 0.8452233 0.3058013 1.0896865
 [8,] 0.5742021 0.8816770 1.4622064
 [9,] 1.7673249 0.9863849 1.1386831
[10,] 0.9001773 1.0793596 0.5754467
```